# JDBC DB DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, glassfish

I am trying to connect to a DB2 database with GlassFish. I wrote a little test application without a GlassFish contet, containing only a main method where I got the same error message:

> A DRDA Data Stream Syntax Error was detected. Reason: 0x3. ERRORCODE=-4499

I looked on Google and found several possible causes:

1. Firewall
2. Driver version
3. No tcp/ip configuration is activated on the database side
4. Windows network configuration does not have tcip/ip configuration enabled
   (checkbox tcp/ip not being checked)

None of these are the case.
Does anyone else have an idea where to look further?

Comment: Complete refactoring of the question: grammer, formatting, build-up etc.

Answer (score 1):

Give more details.

- What (DB2) driver (and version) are you using to connect to DB2?
        Are   you using a type-2 driver, or a type-4 driver?

  - Are you able to connect to the same database from the same    Microsoft-Windows computer without using glassfish, for example,
    connecting via the command-line (db2cmd.exe), or connecting via ODBC 
    or via the db2ca (if installed).
      can you telnet to the specific DB2-port on the remote hostname?
      Is your target database running on DB2    for Z/OS or DB2 for    i-Series (AS/400) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am using type 4 driver (4.14.146) for DB2  v9.7.9.  At the moment i have not tested to connect via ODBC or the db2 command line tools (they are not available). Telnet is ok. I try it on the port of the database. The db2 database is working on a windows system.

Comment: The 4.14.146 driver version is shipped with DB2 V9.7 fixpack 11 software.  The DB2 V9.7.9 uses driver 4.14.137. You can use the DB2 V9.7 runtime client to verify the connection at the command line - I'd say this is an important elimination step. This runtime client is a small footprint install if it is not already installed. Post also the glassfish configuration for your type-4 driver specific stuff (classname and properties and connection url details).